# Sonarqube 5.1.2 native package on RHEL6 won't start without root

Tags: sonarqube, rpm, startupscript, startup-error

I have recently installed the native RPM package of Sonarqube 5.1.2 on my RHEL 6.6 server.
I'm using 64 bit OpenJDK 1.8.0_51 and MySQL as DB.
Sonarqube starts up perfectly with root using the sonar.sh script in /bin within the installation folder (which is /opt/sonar in my case) but it doesn't work with the startup script created by the package in /etc/init.d.

Here is the log export:

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Using tick timer.
wrapperp | server listening on port 32000.
wrapper  | Command[0] : /etc/alternatives/java_sdk/bin/java
wrapper  | Command[1] : -Djava.awt.headless=true
wrapper  | Command[2] : -Xms3m
wrapper  | Command[3] : -Xmx32m
wrapper  | Command[4] : -Djava.library.path=./lib
wrapper  | Command[5] : -classpath
wrapper  | Command[6] : ../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:../../lib/sonar-application-5.1.2.jar
wrapper  | Command[7] : -Dwrapper.key=sdELP0aWwf4S5hdM
wrapper  | Command[8] : -Dwrapper.port=32000
wrapper  | Command[9] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000
wrapper  | Command[10] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999
wrapper  | Command[11] : -Dwrapper.debug=TRUE
wrapper  | Command[12] : -Dwrapper.pid=23176
wrapper  | Command[13] : -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3
wrapper  | Command[14] : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper
wrapper  | Command[15] : -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10
wrapper  | Command[16] : -Dwrapper.jvmid=1
wrapper  | Command[17] : org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper  | Command[18] : org.sonar.application.App
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | WrapperManager class initialized by thread: main  Using classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: JVM #1
jvm 1    | Running a 64-bit JVM.
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: Registering shutdown hook
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: Using wrapper
jvm 1    | Load native library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform specific libraries do not exist.
jvm 1    | Loading native library failed: libwrapper-linux-x86-64.so  Cause: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-linux-x86-64 in java.library.path
jvm 1    | Loaded native library: libwrapper.so
jvm 1    | Calling native initialization method.
jvm 1    | Inside native WrapperManager initialization method
jvm 1    | Java Version   : 1.8.0_51-b16 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
jvm 1    | Java VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | Startup runner thread started.
jvm 1    | Control event monitor thread started.
jvm 1    | WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp@4a574795, args[]) called by thread: main
jvm 1    | Communications runner thread started.
jvm 1    | Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
jvm 1    | Failed attempt to bind using local port 31000
jvm 1    | Opened Socket from 31001 to 32000
jvm 1    | Send a packet KEY : sdELP0aWwf4S5hdM
jvm 1    | handleSocket(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=32000,localport=31001])
wrapperp | accepted a socket from 127.0.0.1 on port 31001
wrapperp | read a packet KEY : sdELP0aWwf4S5hdM
wrapper  | Got key from JVM: sdELP0aWwf4S5hdM
wrapperp | send a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
wrapperp | send a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
wrapperp | send a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
wrapper  | Start Application.
wrapperp | send a packet START : start
jvm 1    | Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 1
jvm 1    | Received a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
jvm 1    | PingTimeout from Wrapper is 0
jvm 1    | Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
jvm 1    | Received a packet START : start
jvm 1    | calling WrapperListener.start()
jvm 1    | Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
jvm 1    | WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook started
jvm 1    | WrapperManager.stop(0) called by thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
jvm 1    | Send a packet STOP : 0
jvm 1    | Startup runner thread stopped.
wrapperp | read a packet STOP : 0
wrapper  | JVM requested a shutdown. (0)
wrapper  | wrapperStopProcess(0) called.
wrapper  | Sending stop signal to JVM
wrapperp | send a packet STOP : NULL
jvm 1    | Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
wrapperp | read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
wrapper  | JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
jvm 1    | Thread, Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook, handling the shutdown process.
jvm 1    | shutdownJVM(0) Thread:Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
jvm 1    | Send a packet STOPPED : 0
wrapperp | read a packet STOPPED : 0
wrapper  | JVM signalled that it was stopped.
jvm 1    | Closing socket.
wrapperp | socket read no code (closed?).
wrapperp | server listening on port 32001.
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook complete
wrapper  | JVM exited normally.
wrapper  | Signal trapped.  Details:
wrapper  |   signal number=17 (SIGCHLD), source="unknown"
wrapper  | Received SIGCHLD, checking JVM process status.
wrapper  | JVM process exited with a code of 0, leaving the wrapper exit code set to 0.
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I know it must be something with the permissions for the "sonar" user which was also created by the install package and I already made sure that the /opt/sonar folder is owned by the sonar user but still, these logs can't tell me what is missing.
I also compared the above log with the one when I start the script with the root user and I was able to point out at least some differences.

With root, after invoking the main method, the actual java process starts properly:

```
.
.
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
jvm 1    | INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.51-1.b16.el6_7.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process3395120832375267732properties
```

With the sonar user, its not started and the JVM (or wrapper) simply initiates a shutdown:

```
.
.
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook started
jvm 1    | WrapperManager.stop(0) called by thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what might be missing from the sonar user because according to the RPM package description, the startup script should work without root privileges.

Can anyone help me or point me to the right direction? I really don't want to run Sonarqube as root if it's not necessary.

Thank you for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialy start sonar using root account (via sonar.sh) ?
If so, did you chown -r /opt/sonar directory to sonar user ?

Comment: In addition you can check logs in "/opt/sonar/logs" to see what's happening with SonarQube, when starting using script from "/etc/init.d".

Comment: @hgomez: Yes, I initially started it with /opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh and yes, all files and folders within /opt/sonar are owned by the sonar user (it was done automatically after yum finished with the installation but I checked it anyway and they are correctly set),

Comment: @Godin: The logs you see above are exported from the /opt/sonar/logs and the reason why I opened this question is because those logs are not giving me any directions regarding the actual problem.

Comment: @Dzoda could you try to switch to "sonar" user with "su" and then execute "java -jar /opt/sonar/lib/sonar-application-5.1.2.jar -Dsonar.log.console=true" ?

Comment: @Godin: I did what you asked but nothing seem to be happening when I execute the command. Should I see something in other logs or in the shell?

Comment: @Dzoda You're supposed to see SonarQube startup with logging to console.